# Difference between splitByWholeSeparator, splitPreserveAllTokens, and splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens

Tags: java, split, apache-stringutils, apache-commons-lang3

In the `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` class, what is the difference between `splitByWholeSeparator(String, String)`, `splitPreserveAllTokens(String, String)` and `splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens(String, String)`?  I checked the [JavaDoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) and it is not clear at all why I would use one method over the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some looking over the documentation I see what may be the problem.

1. `split` takes the separator string and treats every character in it as a separator char. Adjacent separator chars are seen as one, no empty array elements.
2. `splitPreserveAllTokens` does the same but adjacent separator chars lead to empty array elements.
3. `splitByWholeSeparator` uses the whole separator string to split the string. Adjacent separator strings are seen as one, no empty array elements.
4. `splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens` does the same but but adjacent separator strings lead to empty array elements.

*Note:*
The function always adds the remaining characters after the last separator. If the String ends with a separator it adds an empty String because there is no remaining length check at that point.

An example:

```
String: "a,b,;,;e,f,,g,h"
Separator: ",;"

split: ["a","b","e","f,"g",h"]
splitPreserveAllTokens: ["a","b","","","","e","f","","g","h"]
splitByWholeSeparator: ["a,b","e,f,,g,h"]
splitByWholeSeparatorPreserveAllTokens: ["a,b","","e,f,,g,h"]
```

Comment: String stringObj = "::Hello::World::";
String[] split = StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(stringObj, "::");

why is it containing an empty String element?

Comment: @RashidRaza The function **always** adds the _remaining_ characters after the last separator. If the `String` ends with a separator it adds an empty `String` because there is no remaining length check at that point.